# Pass histogram equalized image to second pass hist eq?

Tags: image-processing

Suppose that a digital image is subjected to histogram equalization. The problem is the following: Show that a second pass histogram equalization (on the histogram equalized image) will produce exactly the same result as the first pass?

Here is the solution :- [problem 3.7](http://zangedanesh.com/dl/Digital%20Image%20processing%20Gonzalez%20-%20Solution%20Manual%20_3rd%20edition_.pdf)

I am not able to understand the following part of the answer: because every pixel (and no others) with value r_k is mapped to s_k, n_{s_k}=n_{r_k}.

Answer (score 2):

This fact stems from the assumptions made on the transformation T representing the histogram equalization operation:

a. T is single-valued and monotonically increasing;

b. T(r) is in [0, 1] for every r in [0,1].

See the corresponding chapter in "Digital Image Processing" by Gonzalez and Woods. In particular, it can be verified that these two assumptions hold for the discrete histogram normalization (equations see Problem 3.7) - at least if none of the intensity values is 0, because then T is strictly monotonic implying a one-to-one mapping; this in turn implies the fact that only every pixel with value r_k is mapped to s_k and no other intensity values. This is done in the solution of Problem 3.10 in the PDF you provided. If one (or more) intensity value(s) is (are) 0, this might not be the case anymore. However, in the continuous domain (in which histogram equalization is usually derived), both assumptions hold, as is shown in the corresponding Chapter in the book by Gonzalez and Woods.